# Migrate data from iPhone 4 to iPhone 4s

Tags: upgrade, iphone, migration

I have a Verizon iPhone 4. What the easiest way to migrate my data & settings from the iPhone 4 to a new Verizon iPhone 4s [I'm expecting one in a few days]?  I want my new iPhone 4s to be just like my current iPhone 4 but with IOS5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plug in your old iPhone 4. In iTunes, right click on the device in the left column. Choose "Back up" from the listing. When the back up is complete, disconnect the device.

Next, plug in your iPhone 4S. Pull up the context menu again but this time choose "Restore from Backup..." and choose the most current back up from the list.

[image]